# Flutter firebase silent sign in not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web

I am working on a webapp with flutter using firebase auth. I need a silent sign in functionality. This is what I tried:
my build method in main.dart:

```
       return user != null
    ? FutureBuilder(
        future: widget._userRepo.getUserById(user.uid),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (user != null) {
              BlocProvider.of<SignInCubit>(context)
                  .setInitialUserData(snapshot.data);
            }
            return MaterialApp(
                title: 'Name',
                theme: ThemeData(
                    highlightColor: CustomColours.darkBlue,
                    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                        bodyColor: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'FuturaLight')),
                home: width > height
                    ? /*CodePage(_gameRepo, _heroRepo, _tournamentRepo, _userRepo,
                        "123456", _teamRepo)*/
                    LandingPage(
                        widget._tournamentRepo,
                        widget._userRepo,
                        widget._gameRepo,
                        widget._heroRepo,
                        widget._teamRepo)
                    : NoMobilePage());
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        })
    : MaterialApp(
        title: 'Name',
        theme: ThemeData(
            highlightColor: CustomColours.darkBlue,
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'FuturaLight')),
        home: width > height
            ? /*CodePage(_gameRepo, _heroRepo, _tournamentRepo, _userRepo,
                        "123456", _teamRepo)*/
            LandingPage(widget._tournamentRepo, widget._userRepo,
                widget._gameRepo, widget._heroRepo, widget._teamRepo)
            : NoMobilePage());
```

the method in hte userRepo:

```
  Future<CustomUser> getUserById(String id) async {
final Map<String, dynamic> userData =
    await _userDataService.getUserById(id);
if (userData == null) {
  return null;
} else {
  return CustomUser.fromJson(userData);
}
}
```

the userService:

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserById(String id) async {
if (id == null) {
  return null;
}
DocumentSnapshot document =
    await _firebaseFirestore.collection(_collectionPath).doc(id).get();

return document.data();
```

}
I get the user from here, in main.dart:

```
 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<User> user;
  @override
  void initState() {
    user = widget._googleSignInRepo.getUser();

    super.initState();
  }
```

this is the getUser function:

```
 User getUser() {
return _googleAuthService.getUser();
```

}

However, when I run it, the user variable is an error:"<getObject: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uri' was called on null.>".What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that interacts with Firebase Authentication. Where does `user` come from in the `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: In recent versions of `firebase_auth`, the `currentUser` variable does not return a `Future`, but a `User?`: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: we are using this  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1

Comment: Any specific reason for not using the latest version? It's a lot harder to help with older versions. From a quick search a clean build might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170915/flutter-build-runner-not-working-the-getter-uri-was-called-on-null

Comment: We have started by using older versions, and have not had the time to udpate yet. We have got it working up until one refresh, but after a second it doesn't sign us in. Do ou have any idea why this could happen? Thanks you for your help, I have updated the code to the current version.